# Syntax Error in CREATE TABLE Statement in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, syntax

I have created a table called Customers with a CustomerID, Last Name, First Name, Address, and City, but when I tried to use the INSERT INTO to add data and ran the SQL Statement, it gives me an error: "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement". Below is the SQL Statement I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
CustomerID int,
LastName varchar(50),
FirstName varchar(50),
Address varchar(50),
City varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO (CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City) 
    VALUES ('10001', 'Smith', 'John', '1002 Danville Road', 'Louisville');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the table name from your `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)
VALUES ('10001', 'Smith', 'John', '1002 Danville Road', 'Louisville');
```

As to why you got an error pointing to your `CREATE TABLE` statement (which looks correct), my guess is that Access tried to connect the botched `INSERT` statement to the create in an effort to parse everything correctly.